# jQuery: trying to add a class to an element that at the beginning is an string:

Tags: jquery

Im  trying to add a class to an element that at the beginning is an string:

```
var foobar = '<div>hello</div>';
$(foobar).addClass('my_class');
$('body').append($(foobar));
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5zxttcjy/1/)

but the class name is not added..

Comment: Checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5zxttcjy/13/

Answer (score 3):

`addClass()` after appending the element. Like this:

```
$(foobar).appendTo('body').addClass('my_class');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgv67oh7/)**

Answer (score 0):

.addClass only works on DOM elements. since foobar is a string, you should use the [.replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var foobar = foobar.replace("<div>", "<div class='my_class'>"); 
$('body').append($(foobar));
```

Comment: He has a jQuery wrapper which makes it a jQuery element: `$(foobar)`